# How do I fetch attribute's value of any element in Angular?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

We can define an attribute in angular the following ways:

```
ng:model="name"
ng_model="name"
ng-model="name"
data-ng-model="name"
x-data-ng-model="name"
```

When I try to get the attribute value using [.attr('ng-model')](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)  then it ignores the other variants.

Is there any way in angular to get the attribute's value regardless of how it was used?

Comment: if it is in a directive, angularjs provides `attrs` object in which you can call `attrs.ngModel`

Comment: Thanks Arun, I'm aware of that but can I get access to attrs object using `angular.element('div').attrs`.

Comment: can you put everything in context? maybe `anElement.getAttribute('type')` ?

Comment: That does not work if I call `anElement.getAttribute('ng-model')` but data-ng-model was used.

Comment: angular normalises names of attributes. maybe you have to use `ngModel`? it's hard to guess without knowing the context though

Comment: In my [opensource project](https://github.com/codef0rmer/angular-dragdrop/commit/ac013d68cfe74101dbb78ea0fc7cef04688ac71a#L0R289), i'm having this issue. Meanwhile I decided to write a custom jQuery method to support `myModel` and `data-myModel` only. But angular recognizes any format such as `data-ng:bind` or `data:ng:bind` or `data:ng_bind` etc. - there are N numbers of combinations which I did not support.